# How to calculate CVSS v3.0 Base score when there is missing data in Attack Vector or Attack Complexity etc

Tags: security

I am encountering the situation where certain fields like Attack Vector, Attack Complexity and Privileges Required are missing, what shall I deal with them when calculating the base score for each case?

Should I assign a value to it or completely delete the case?

Comment: CVSS is for assigning a score to an actual, concrete vulnerability. How could information on eg. attack complexity be missing? Can you elaborate, maybe give an example?

Comment: @GaborLengyel Hi this is in a dataset, I eventually decide to drop the missing data row. Thanks